# Run Distributed Tests using TFS 2015

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, integration-testing, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

Recently I started building a test infrastructure and I am running into some issues. The background is that I want to run my tests for two platforms 64bit and 32bit. It works fine for 32bit and 64bit, if the test assemblies are managed. The problem occurs when the assemblies are native (C++). When I run the configuration for 64bit (only native) mode it says:

"A 64-bit test cannot run in a 32-bit process. Specify platform as X64 to force test run in X64 mode on X64 machine."

If I go to the test machine and look at the DTAExecutionHost log file it loads the following settings:
[image]

I do not see any option to change the TargetPlatform in the vNext build process (Run Functional Tests item). Does anybody knows how can I run 64bit native unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can source control your own `.runsettings` file and tell the test agent to load that instead of the default.

Comment: Okay but the build process item "Run Functional Tests" allows to pass a setting file just for the MSTest element. Maybe I am missing something, could you explain how can I load the modified .runsetting file?